# How do i find the actual outliers in the boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have a boxplot that looks like this:
[image: boxplot]

From what I understand about outliers, the dots that are above the maximum line are outliers but how do I find the points that are actually outliers as I don't think that all the supposed outliers are actually outliers?

Comment: For your purposes, what do you consider an outlier?

Comment: Also, can you include your data run as plot(density(yourData)) so we can see the distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/whisker-of-boxplot/) which matches my recollection, the whiskers are calculated as (pseudocode):

```
upper whisker = min(max(x), Q_3 + 1.5 * IQR)
lower whisker = max(min(x), Q_1 – 1.5 * IQR)
```

Any points outside the whiskers are deemed to be outliers.

If you want to inspect outlier points, you can assign the output of `boxplot` and look at the `out` field as the help page suggests:

> ```
>  out: the values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes
>       of the whiskers.
> ```

Something like

```r
box <- boxplot(rnorm(100))
box$out
```

Answer (score 4):

Use functionality of `boxplot` object:

```
set.seed(59737908)

x <- c(rnorm(10), 10, -55)

outliers <- boxplot(x, plot = F)$out
outliers
#[1]  10 -55
```

P.S. @alan was first